# removing old lxc directory "operation not permitted"

Tags: 13.04, lxc

I setup some lxc containers (raring) under a /data path to get them off my SSD and I thought they were corrupt so tried to just rm -rf /data/lxc/$name and it clears out all except the rootfs directory. It fails with the error:

```
sudo rm -rf /data/lxc/$lxcname
   rm: cannot remove ‘/data/lxc/$lxcname/rootfs’: Operation not permitted
```

Any hints on how I can clear this now empty directory would be appreciated.

Comment: sudo su and then remove it

Comment: also check lxc-destroy

Comment: `sudo su` should never be recommended.  Use `sudo -i`        Thanks to guntbert

Comment: Even after using sudo -i, I cannot remove the two directories. I still get the same operation not permitted message.

Comment: Is your lxc directory on a btrfs partition? The symptoms are similar to the case where rootfs subdirectory is a btrfs subvolume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same exact problem as you.  After reading @vhallac's comment and doing some digging, I discovered that btrfs requires any subvolumes to be deleted before a parent path can be deleted.  Subvolumes are removed using the `btrfs subvolume delete <subvolume-path>` command.

For your case, try first using `$ sudo btrfs subvolume delete /data/lxc/$lxcname/rootfs`, then you should be able to run the usual `sudo rm -rf /data/lxc/$lxcname`.

See also:
[BTRFS command documentation](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs%28command%29)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that I decided to test out btrfs on this volume that houses my lose-able data like lxc containers. That worked for getting rid of my old directories.